# How to Reload JSON data in Fullcalendar?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, fullcalendar

I am using Fullcalendar.

In my case I am adding Custom Events, Like when user clicks on specific date, he can add his event, when he is done with insertion, the custom event he just added show automatically appear on calendar, means the fresh JSON Data should reload and appear.

Here is my code:

```
events      : "ajax/response.php",//Fetching JSON From PHP File//

function insertEventSchedule()
{

    var title           = $('#titl').val();
    var fromDate        = $('#fromDate').val();
    var toDate          = $('#toDate').val();

        $.ajax({
                        type: "POST",
                        url : "ajax/insert_schedule_event.php",
                        data: "title="+title+"&fromDate="+fromDate+"&toDate="+toDate+"&timeStamp="+$.now(), 
                        cache: false,
                        beforeSend:  function() 
                            {
                                $('.submit_data').html('<img src="include/content/loaders/ajax-loader.gif" width="20">');
                            },
                        success: function(html)
                            {
                                $('#myPopup').dialog('close');  
                            }
                     });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to build an event Object and render that event using the [renderEvent](http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/event_rendering/renderEvent/) method before or after closing your dialog

**UPDATE**

```
var newEvent = new Object();

newEvent.title = "some text";
newEvent.start = new Date();
newEvent.allDay = false;
// ...
$('#calendar').fullCalendar( 'renderEvent', newEvent );
```

The complete list of event attribute are [here](http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/event_data/Event_Object/)

Comment: can you give me a simple example ?

Comment: I will call : $('#calendar').fullCalendar( 'renderEvent', newEvent ); where i close my popup right?

Comment: Its giving me an error: ReferenceError: newEvent is not defined

Comment: Have you created the event?? In my example you can see "var newEvent = ..." . You have to copy paste the whole code.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/42917/discussion-between-code-hunter-and-storm-buster)